# Generate list of distinct dimensions in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, data-warehouse

I have a table with 3 dimensions- A, B, and C.
I essentially want values of all possible combinations for these dimensions and populate all measures(M) as 0 when a combination isn't present.

Suppose I have the table-

[image]

If I do this I get -

```
select a,b,c from sum(m) fact group by a,b,c
```

[image]

But I would like all possible combinations, -

[image]

Currently, I a doing a cross join like below, but is there some faster way to do this (as my table has about ~1M records)?  -

```
select * from (
select distinct f1.a, f2.b, f3.c 
from fact f1 
cross join fact f2 
cross join fact f3 ) all
left join 
( select a,b,c from sum(m) fact group by a,b,c) s
on all.a=s.a and all.b=s.b and all.c=s.c
```

Comment: What is your database? MySQL is not Oracle and Oracle is not MySQL. They both differ in functionality. As long as you tagged DWH I presume this is actually Oracle, but please remove unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1):

If this is Oracle Database, then this is exactly what `cube` is for.

```
select a, b, c, sum(m) 
from my_table 
group by cube(a,b,c)
```

Comment: `cube` does not generate combinations that do not exist in source data. It generates all possible permutations of dimensions, not values. You may check it in the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5784b7446a41d3e4c1c3fef1c005c56d): there's no `(1,2)` tuple

Answer (score 1):

MySQL:

`GROUP BY a,b,c` will produce 1 row per combination that exists in the table.

If you want all possible combinations, you need to build 1 (or 3) more tables to list all the possible values, then do a `LEFT JOIN` from them.  You may also want `COALESCE(col, 0)` to turn `NULLs` into zeros.